# How to place div at the center of browser

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

[image: something like in the image]
I'm working on mobile app. I'm trying to align an image outside the div, but couldnt.
pls help me , thanks in advance .
this is what i tried

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-position='fixed'>
     <h1>Center table</h1>

</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="centeredTable">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/26/26/food/1/" ; />
                </td>
                <td><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all custom-btn ui-shadow ui-mini">sunday</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/26/26/food/1/" ; /></div>
```

```
div.centeredTable {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 400px;
background-color: #bbb
  }
.centeredTable table {
width: 100%;
 }
 .centeredTable td {
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
 }
.centeredTable tr td:first-child {
width: 20%;
 }
 .centeredTable tr td:last-child {
width: 80%;
}
```

I have another image which i want to fit outside the div, which i'm not able to.
if i do so, div will be no more at the center

Comment: _I'm trying to align an image outside the div_  you mean inside?

Comment: @ Dhaval , i have a table inside the div (in that table i got image and a button). out of this div (completely out) i would like to add another image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add class to imgs parent, for example centeredImage:

```
<div class="centeredImage">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/26/26/food/1/" ; />
</div>
```

Then add CSS style:

```
.centeredImage {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/debute/Eqr8x/)

Comment: @ debute, i want the image in the same line

Comment: First, you will need to set some width on your `content` and also set `float: left` and finaly `centerImage` must be `inline-block` (`default` is `block`, which is whole line). Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/debute/Eqr8x/1/